# onActivityCreated remove layout of Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to create an application which deals with fragments.
First, build an application login without using fragments and it worked perfectly, but I tried to be more constructive and create a menu done for me.
I was trying to migrate all that created the Activity Log for Fragments but I'm having trouble trying to pass everything from a place to another.

What happens to me now is that I have actions that were being created in the OnCreate (Activity) and tried to pass all the functions for onCreateView (Fragments) but when I return from view, is not shown me in app layout that was supposed to.

MainActivity:

```
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private NavigationView nvDrawer;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //set tolbar
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //Find our drawer view
        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerToggle = setupDrawerContent();

        // Tie DrawerLayout events to the ActionBarToggle
        mDrawer.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

        // Find our drawer view
        nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);
        // Setup drawer view
        setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);

    }

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle setupDrawerContent() {
        return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open,  R.string.drawer_close);
    }

    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                        return true;
                    }
                });

    }

    public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
        // Create a new fragment and specify the planet to show based on
        // position
        Fragment fragment = null;

        Class fragmentClass = null;
        switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_first_fragment:
                fragmentClass = FirstFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_second_fragment:
                fragmentClass = SecondFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_third_fragment:
                fragmentClass = ThirdFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_status_fragment:
                fragmentClass = LoginStatusFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_login_fragment:
                fragmentClass = LoginFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_register_fragment:
                fragmentClass = ThirdFragment.class;
                break;
            default:
                fragmentClass = FirstFragment.class;
        }

        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.flContent, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        //fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

        // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
        mDrawer.closeDrawers();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // Make sure this is the method with just `Bundle` as the signature
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

LoginStatusFragment:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.HashMap;

import helper.SQLiteHandler;
import helper.SessionManager;

/**
 * Created by NB21094 on 24/11/2015.
 */
public class LoginStatusFragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView txtName;
    private TextView txtEmail;
    private Button btnLogout;
    private Context context;
    private SQLiteHandler db;
    private SessionManager session;
    private View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_loginstatus, container, false);

        context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

        txtName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        txtEmail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email);
        btnLogout = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);

        // SqLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(context);

        // session manager
        session = new SessionManager(context);

        if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
            logoutUser();
        }

        // Fetching user details from sqlite
        HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();

        String name = user.get("name");
        String email = user.get("email");

        // Displaying the user details on the screen
        txtName.setText(name);
        txtEmail.setText(email);

        // Logout button click event
        btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                logoutUser();
            }
        });
        return view;
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_loginstatus, container, false);
    }
       /**
     * Logging out the user. Will set isLoggedIn flag to false in shared
     * preferences Clears the user data from sqlite users table
     * */
    private void logoutUser() {
        session.setLogin(false);

        db.deleteUsers();

        // Launching the login activity
        /*Intent intent = new Intent(LoginStatusActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();*/
        changeFragment("main");
    }

    private void changeFragment(String option){
        Fragment fragment = null;

        Class fragmentClass = null;
        if(option.contains("loginstatus")){
            fragmentClass = LoginStatusFragment.class;
        } else if (option.contains("register")){
            //fragmentClass = LogoutFragment.class;
        } else if (option.contains("main")) {
            fragmentClass = FirstFragment.class;
        }

        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();
    }

}
```

activity_loginstatus.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" > -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/welcome"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/lbl_name"
            android:textSize="24dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
            android:background="@color/btn_logut_bg"
            android:text="@string/btn_logout"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<!-- </RelativeLayout> -->
```

Can you please help me?
The layout never appear and i dont know why.

Comment: Which layout never appears?

Comment: can you show the layout file?  perhaps the fragment is getting created but is not being shown because of the layout.

Comment: i just update the question with layout file.

Comment: the problem is: if onCreateView only have this line 'return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_loginstatus, container, false);' show me the layout above.
But i need the rest of the code and if i have it there, the layout that appears on my app is the "default" in MainActivity.